# What version of openSUSE would be closest to SLES 12.3?

Tags: opensuse, suse

I have not been able to find any resource that maps the relation between a release of openSUSE and SLES. One way is to compare the package on distro watch.  Can anyone point me to the release of openSUSE on which SLES 12.3 was based on?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the full map of distro help you:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg